# Best way to perform a GET request without any other librairies

Tags: android, apache, http, lib

It looks like the Apache client is deprecated, is there another way to do http request without installing fancy libraries ?

Should I use the Apache client anyway ? How do I import it, my Android Studio do not want to import HttpClient, HttpGet, ...

Thanks

Comment: HttpUrlConnection

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you tried HttpURlConnection?

Here's a sample code that get the image from a server and displaying it to a Image view:

```
private class SendHttpRequestTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap> {
            @Override
            protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... params) {
                try {
                    URL url = new URL("http://xxx.xxx.xxx/image.jpg");
                    HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                    connection.setDoInput(true);
                    connection.connect();
                    InputStream input = connection.getInputStream();
                    Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input);
                    return myBitmap;
                }catch (Exception e){
                    Log.e(TAG,e.getMessage());
                }
                return null;
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {
                    ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(ID OF YOUR IMAGE VIEW);
                    imageView.setImageBitmap(result);
            }
    }
```

I hope i could help

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
URL url = new URL("your URL in String");
HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
conn.connect();
int httpResponse = conn.getResponseCode();
```

Comment: I will check this out !
How do I put extra paramter like this : 
https://i.imgur.com/oNEjDVl.png

Comment: you can add with your URL. Get request not have param if you have any than you have to append with URL. have look in you image url there you can put it after "?".

Comment: even you can use JSON Object (make sure your server accept JSON data )